# How do I add an arbitrary value to a TensorFlow summary?

Tags: logging, tensorflow, tensorboard

In order to log a simple value `val` to a TensorBoard summary I need to

```
val = 5
test_writer.add_summary(sess.run(tf.scalar_summary('test', val)), global_step)
```

Is

```
sess.run(tf.scalar_summary('test', val))
```

really necessary to get `val` added as a summary?

Comment: Answered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37902705/how-to-manually-create-a-tf-summary

Comment: @Peteris: Yes, that looks like a duplicate.

Comment: Check this useful solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37915182/7048895

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can construct the summary by yourself, like

```
from tensorflow.core.framework import summary_pb2

value = summary_pb2.Summary.Value(tag="Accuracy", simple_value=0.95)
summary = summary_pb2.Summary(value=[value])
```

you can then add `summary` using `add_summary` like in your code.

Answer (score 12):

Here's another (perhaps slightly more up-to-date) solution with the tf.Summary.FileWriter class:

```
summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(logdir=output_dir)
value = tf.Summary.Value(tag='variable name', simple_value=value)
summary_writer.add_event(summary=tf.summary.Event(tf.Summary([value]),
                         wall_time=time.time(),
                         step=global_step))
```

Then you can create your SummarySaverHook as such:

```
summary_hook = tf.train.SummarySaverHook(
    summary_writer=summary_writer,
    summary_op=your_summary_op)
```

which you can pass to your MonitoredTrainingSession. An example of a summary_op is `tf.summary.merge_all()`

NOTE: You will have to wait for the FileWriter to flush for it to appear in your events file. You can force it by calling `summary_writer.flush()`

---

A simpler solution:

```
summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(output_dir)
summary = tf.Summary()
summary.value.add(tag='name of var', simple_value=value)
summary_writer.add_summary(summary, global_step)
summary_writer.flush()
```

Comment: FileWriter.add_event is very useful if one wants to change the wall_time that is serialized